# php - ssh2_exec failed allocating pty

Tags: php, ssh

Using PHP, I need to periodically execute a remote command on a Draytek 2925 router using SSH.

I can already connect to the router using the standard "ssh" command on Linux, but after authenticating I am getting "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0". However despite that message, I can still send commands.

When I try doing the same with PHP, I am getting 1 of 2 results and neither of which is returning the results I need.

My code is as follows:

```
<?
if (!($connection = ssh2_connect('my.router.local', 22)))
    die('CONN');
else if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'admin', 'password'))
    die('AUTH');
else
{
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'sys version');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
    exit();
}
?>
```

The PHP fails at ssh2_exec(). If I specify the 3rd argument (pty), I get this result:

```
Warning: ssh2_exec(): Failed allocating 1 pty at 80x25 characters
```

However, not specifying the 3rd argument results in:

```
Warning: ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host
```

Even if I type @ssh2_exec(), I don't get a warning, but I don't get a result either.

If PHP is a no-go, I tried using sshpass in the same way, but that results in the following:

```
# sshpass -f sshpwd -v ssh admin@my.router.local 'sys version'
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
SSHPASS read: admin@my.router.local's password:
SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS read:

exec request failed on channel 0
#
```

I ultimately just need to authenticate, send a command and return the result. Is there anything I am doing wrong or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my query by using TELNET instead. Yes it's not secure like SSH, but since it's being used internally over the LAN, it doesn't matter.

For anyone interested, I used [Net_Telnet](https://github.com/jnorell/Net_Telnet) and the following code:

```
<?php
require_once "Net/Telnet.php";

$router   = 'my.router.local';
$password = 'password';

try
{
    $t = new Net_Telnet($router);
    $t->connect();

    $t->login([
                  'login_prompt'  => 'Account:',
                  'login_success' => ' User login successful, expired time is "Unlimited".',
                  'login_fail'    => '% Access denied',
                  'login'         => 'admin',
                  'password'      => $password,
                  'prompt'        => "{$router}>",
              ]
    );

    echo $t->cmd('sys version');

    $t->disconnect();

    // catch any buffered data
    echo $t->get_data();
    echo "\n";
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Caught Exception ('{$e->getMessage()}')\n{$e}\n";
}

exit();
?>
```

Which results in:

```
# php -f telnet.php
 sys version
Router Model: Vigor2925n    Version: 3.8.4 English
Profile version: 3.0.0    Status: 1 (0x48245e4c)
Router IP: 0.0.0.0    Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Firmware Build Date/Time: Dec 15 2016 17:26:01
Router Name: my.router.local
Revision: 61327 V384_2925

>
#
```